# Calling SQL Procedure: SQL exception - code: 6550 ORA-06550

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle10g

Trying to call `SQL` procedure:

```
PROCEDURE Incident_inqr
(MSISDN IN VARCHAR2
, Topic IN varchar2
,Incident_id IN varchar2 default '20120401' 
, RESULT OUT number
);
```

java JDBC string:

```
SQL command: begin ? := SMASTER.SERVICE.Incident_inqr ( '9308000050','6345_NN','20120401', ?); end;
```

the error (I'm getting it in Russian):

> SQL exception - code: 6550 ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 13: PLS-00222:
>   функция с именем 'INCIDENT_INQR' не существует в этой области действия
>   ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

translated:

> SQL exception - code: 6550 ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00222:
>   function called 'INCIDENT_INQR' does not exist in this action area
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL / SQL: Statement ignored

output `?` registration:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Incident_inqr` is a procedure. So it has no return value but just the `out` parameter.

The proper way to call it thus is:

```
begin SMASTER.SERVICE.Incident_inqr ( '9308000050','6345_NN','20120401', ?); end;
```

...

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

Furthermore, the procedure needs to be part of a package called 'SERVICE' in the schema / belonging to the user `SMASTER`.

Comment: _Incident_inqr is a procedure. So it has no return value but just the out parameter._ <- That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that in your metadata/code you call with the procedure with the following name format: `SCHEMA_USERNAME.PACKAGE_NAME.PROCEDURE_NAME`